# Airliner takes off from JFK in 1966, gets stuck in time warp and lands in London in 2016

Tags: time-travel

If an airliner disappeared in 1966 and landed in London 50 years later, without anybody on board being aware that they had been 'lost', what difficulties would they face?
I'm thinking that when the aircraft  took off, JFK was president of the USA  and Obama had been around for 8 years.  £1 would buy £2.79 dollars. Avg 3 bed house in England was £3500 on take-off but £200,000 on landing.
There were no mobile phones and smoking was widespread, even on the aircraft, but when they landed they'd see British police with machine guns and whatever the event or people they were planning to see, would be history.  I omitted to say that they had no idea that they'd been missing for 50 years and hadn't aged.  Everyone on board would have been deemed dead, long ago.   Hope this helps get the creative juices going.

Comment: Culture shock for one. The fact that the cold war is over and the enemy they'd been indoctrinated against is now an 'ally' would probably be rather difficult to grasp. Also the sudden diversity of people. Technology shouldn't bee too much of a problem for them to get used to, considering children can use it.

Comment: Pete, how do you know which date is valid?

Comment: @Molot - the part of the question that says "50 years later" was a bit of a clue here.

Comment: I think there might be some changes in airline standard regarding landing, taxying,... but this goes to aviation SE...

Comment: @Lu22 Children grew up with it and learned when they were young. For an adult that has to learn tech that has been in development for 50 or more years...

Comment: Didn't we have this question on here already? It sounds so familiar..

Comment: @Micheal Karnerfors. I'm not saying it's going to be easy, but a 4 year old with an Ipad has no advantage over a 60 year old using one for the first time. Some rural areas in Africa are technologically behind 60's America, and yet with some education they can use modern technology.

Comment: Unless this event also erased them from their old timeline, they might bump into themselves.

Comment: @Lu22 I think the bigger problem is of the sort "I'm an engineer with 20 years of experience, and almost all of that experience is worthless now". Some experience and skill would still be transferable, some blanks might not be too hard to fill, but you're suddenly an "old guy" on the job, as if you didn't learn anything in the past decade (or 50 years in this case). It's easy to underestimate how things change overtime, and how much of the infrastructure has changed beyond recognition. They couldn't even drive a car, really :D

Comment: @Goufalite When the pilot radios a fuel emergency, "I running out of damned fuel!" they'll clear a runway. Other pilots will see the aircraft and radio, "Yeah, control, there's a Pan-Am Boeing 707 out here..."

Comment: I'm thinking that when the aircraft  took off, JFK was president and £1 would but £2.79 dollars.

Comment: I'm thinking that if the aircraft took off in 1966, everyone on board would think JFK was dead.

Comment: @JohnH "when they landed they'd see British police with machine guns" Oh how quickly people forget. The UK saw plenty of terrorism from the late 1960's and on-wards, as did for instance Germany. The state that we have today is **nothing** compared Europe in the latter half of the 1900's. Also I would like to point out that **you** are the author and as such **you** are the one that is supposed to have the creative juices flowing, not us. We are here to help you with questions you might have, not come up with your story for you. Worldbuilding is not for story generation for authors.

Comment: And yes, as @MichaelHampton pointed out: JFK died in 1963.

Comment: And one more thing: people in the 1960's are fully aware of the concept of inflation... that is not exactly a mystery to them. Just as they know that the prices in 1966 have much higher numbers than the prices had in 1916, so they would expect that the prices in 2016 have much higher numbers than the ones in 1966. Only if the prices had been **exactly the same** as in the 1960's I think they would have been shocked.

Comment: The BBC did this as a radio play ... not that long after 1966, I'm thinking around 1980. The airliner was a biplane, the crew were amazed that note of the other aircraft had propellers. Might have been called "Doppelganger! but I can't remember much more about it and can't find relevant links anywhere atm.

Comment: Just remember about proper landing; quite a few things changed in these 50 years; landing procedures, languages, aircrafts, airports...

Comment: "The Doppelganger Machine" ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWgww150870 ... one problem they faced was, no Croydon Aerodrome!

Comment: Similar premise: [Out of Time (Torchwood)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_Time_%28Torchwood%29).

Comment: If they were going to a Joni Mitchell or The Who concert, they'd be in good shape.

Comment: @MatthewRock Procedures might be (somewhat) different today, but Heathrow hasn't moved, and the [guard frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_emergency_frequency) hasn't changed. While you could probably make a whole chapter out of the confusion of landing, that's something I'd expect to maybe take up three or four pages at most.

Comment: "what difficulties would they face?" is rather broad.  Please restrict it to a more specific area.  E.g. What difficulties would they face supporting themselves?  Or finding a job?  Or convincing people that they are real?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Of course, the changes aren't as drastic as would an IT team face, coming from  60s into today's world; still worth noting.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but I don't think the passengers will be leaving JFK airport while JFK is still the president.  It was renamed to JFK International Aiport FOLLOWING his assassination, not prior to the event.

Answer (score 30):

## Instant celebrity and demand

A **verifiable magic event** has taken place for the first time in Earth's history, and these people are the main cast of this drama. Everyone(!) is going to want a piece of them. Media to begin with, but also scientists of all sorts. Anthropologists, psychologists, and the medical scientists will have a field day. And maybe even the military.

This will probably be very taxing on them. Not only is it hard to be in huge demand but the strange formsof demand will be totally bizarre to them.

"You want me to do **what**? Pose for that filthy rag?! How dare you!" * **SLAP** *

## The deaths of loved ones, changes

Fifty years is a long time. The grand-parents and probably a good portion of the collected parents will have passed away. Children will have grown up. Some cities will have withered away and hardly even exist. And those that still do exist will have changed.

## Culture shock

As stated in other answer/comments: the culture shock. The space race and the cold war is over. Gender roles have been completely upended. Religion has been severely downplayed.

Decency standards have become relaxed in some areas and become incredibly uptight in others; especially the attitudes towards minorities have been severely altered. For instance: to them using any of the N-words against African Americans is still kind of OK, especially "Negro", but the rest of society will gasp in horror as soon as they do.

I think you can expect a great part of them try to find solace in church. And you might expect people to seek out the more strict and conservative churches, as they have attitudes that are more in line with their own fifty years outdated dittos.

## Being "reborn"

A very unique problem, but these are people that have passed out of all the systems and need to be introduced to them again, as adults. There will be some very tricky bureaucracy to deal with as they will — essentially — have to go through the immigration process of their respective countries, while being citizens to begin with and having identities, but that are marked as "deceased".

## Reclaiming property

Providing that DNA testing proves that they are indeed who they say are, there will be some pretty taxing issues about property. Possessions will have been inherited, sold or thrown away. Real-estate will have new tenants. There are no legal precedents here and so they will most likely be left without anything they owned, getting back only that which a) has not become obsolete and junked b) the new owners are generous enough to give them c) they were carrying with them on the plane and that has not been ripped apart and atomized by all the scientists and souvenir hunters.

Or there could be some fairly amusing court battles.

## Providing for themselves

People that fly on a trans-atlantic airliner in 1966 will be upper middle to high class. The question is what skills they bring to provide for themselves. When the money from the initial fame runs out.... then what?

This will be a lottery. Some have skills that are time-less. Other have a skill set that has become hopelessly obsolete. Those that can learn fast and adapt will re-learn. Those that do not have that ability, they will have a bad time. Upper class house-wives... oh dear, they will be in for a shock.

And do note they all have a **long** way to go. They have — for instance — never seen a personal computer or a mobile phone. Interactions with information systems that we all find natural...

> — No, you cannot pay with coins on the bus... you need to get a travel pass.
>
> — Ok, where do I get that?
>
> — Over by that booth
>
> — Eh... ok, how do I use this?
>
> — You press the screen to start
>
> — "Press"?
>
> — Like so...
>
> — Oh, you mean "poke". Ok... now what. And where do I put the coins?
>
> — You do not, you need to use a credit or cash card.
>
> — Where do I get one of those? Do I go to the bank?
>
> — No, you just order it on-line...
>
> — "On line"? On what line? A bus line?

...will be a complete mystery to them.

Comment: I think they would have a nice nest-egg after the inevitable book deals, movie deals, talk show circuit... They'll be ok financially.

Comment: @TonyEnnis If they know how to handle that money well, sure. But that's quite unlikely - even if they had the skill where they came from, many of it is not transferable to todays economy. Plenty of rich people become rather poor as soon as the well dries out - it takes considerable skill to build a fortune that lasts. Sure, they could find people to do it for them, but how do they even choose the right guys?

Comment: For the being reborn part, there could be situations where their country itself doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @polku Indeed... there has been many changes since 1966. An iranian citizen for instance might find the chabge to theocracy very unsettling

Comment: The improved computer tech in the form of PCs and phones will definitely be a giant shock as well. Also, the Internet.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors Most of the IT stuff you mention in your last section only arrived within the last 15-20 years though.  You and I learnt that just fine.  They'll be OK too.

Comment: DNA verification may not be as easy as you imply. Where is the reference material going to come from?

Comment: Exactly the same as the struggles MANY of us have TODAY with automatic systems. Honestly I think transit fare collection is a plot by automakers to make sure no new transit customer Ever Comes Back.  $275 fine for botching Proof of Payment? Are you kidding????

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Relatives... alive and — if needs be — dead ones. In some instances there may even be some from themselves. That would certainly be the case in Sweden where we have a blood sample from every natural born citizen, (with a reservation that it may not have existed in 1966 though).

Answer (score 4):

1. **Culture shock** - things are a lot busier/faster than they used to be.  They'll get over it.
2. **Their own deaths** - they'll have been pronounced as dead at some point soon after the plane disappeared in 1966.  There's going to be some paperwork to go through.  Since everyone on the flight will have their passports, at least they'll have some form of identification

I know a few people who still act as though it's the 60's.

Comment: The ID they have isn't going to be trusted much though, 1960s passports were very different from modern ones. I think it might be possible that wives and children could have been travelling on their husband's/father's passport.

Comment: @origimbo - I'm pretty sure that if a plane suddenly appears bearing the same call-sign//aircraft/part numbers as a plane that mysteriously disappeared 50 years ago, it might be understood that everything on board would be 50 years old.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that as soon as anyone realized what "really" happened, the military would be all over this and media or anyone else wouldn't get within a mile of these people or the plane until the military determined whether or not there was any possibility of making a weapon out of this somehow. (Or don't you watch today's paranoid TV/movie plots?)

Answer (score 2):

Merging existing answers, the priority for the world is going to be finding out what happened, in a way which is safe for the world.

None of those passengers are going to get out of a top-level military biohazard containment facility any time soon.  The only two possible causes are an unknown scientific phenomena (magic indistinguishable from, etc.) or alien (non-human) intervention.  It's not too strong to say that the future of the world depends on making sure we're safe from any threat they may pose.

Followup flights and research along the track of the plane, detailed examination of the plane down to molecules, charge and magnetism, all that kind of stuff is a given.

But the obvious question is *are they who they say they are?*  A new scientific miracle would be amazing, but an alien invasion would be equally plausible.  There's no context for something like this.  So those people are going to be going through batteries of tests, for at least months and probably years, to find out exactly what they are and what they know.  And if any of them happen to die before they get out (and I wouldn't bank against that being non-accidental) then the autopsy is going to take that body apart to component cells.

Assuming they're actual people, by the time they've been imprisoned for a couple of years or so, they'll have had plenty of time to acclimatise to the new world they've arrived in.

Comment: Dunno... My compatriots don't have very positive experience with British border control, nevertheless imprisoning for a few years for having terribly expired passport and visa seem a bit excessive by their standards...

Comment: @Shadow1024 It's not border control into Britain (or the US; those guys are **really** nuts), it's border control into Earth!  So far this hasn't been something we've needed to seriously worry about.  Even so, both Russia and the US had very real quarantines on returning astronauts in the early days of space flight, in case Quatermass became a documentary instead of science fiction.  If any government took this less seriously than someone actively spreading Ebola, West Nile, the Black Death, weaponised anthrax and Spanish flu, I would be scared for the survival of every species on the planet.

Answer (score 1):

Not an airliner, but the Torchwood episode "Out of Time" in series 1 has a small aircraft with a few of people on board get lost in time and arrive in the present day. From memory the craft might of been from the 1960's or 50's.

Characters had to deal with trying to integrate into a society that was completely alien to them. Their families and friends had died and they had no skills to get real jobs etc.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_Time_(Torchwood)

Answer (score 1):

This has already happened†.

> Even when the responses to the drug were positive, patients were not always able to cope with the consequences. Rose R was struck by sleeping sickness at the age of 21 and awoke in 1969 to find her world of 1926 had vanished. She remained rooted in the 1920s and, as if the time gap was beyond her comprehension, stopped responding to levodopa.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1885331/

---

† Kinda. A large number of people were infected by a disease and were rendered catatonic for decades, after which they were awakened by a drug.